# twine upload dist. Get an error "is an invalid value for Version"

Tags: python, python-3.x, twine

I am trying to upload my package with `twine upload dist/*` command. and I get an error:

```
Client Error: 'X.Y.ZZ.post0.dev0-g83905ac' is an invalid value for Version. Error:
```

It looks to me that `X.Y.ZZ.post0.dev0-g83905ac` version does satisfy [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/). I don't understand what is going on.

I have created annotetade tag, etc.
I think I have created the tag already.

```
$ git tag -a vX.Y.ZZ  # Don't forget the leading v
fatal: tag 'vX.Y.ZZ' already exists
```

I have noticed that the sdist command returns error:

```
user:package user-13$ python3 setup.py sdist
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:483: UserWarning: The version specified ('X.Y.ZZ.post0.dev0+g83905ac') is an invalid version, this may not work as expected with newer versions of setuptools, pip, and PyPI. Please see PEP 440 for more details.
  "details." % self.metadata.version
```

I do have the newest versions of everything:

```
user:package user-13$ pip3 --version
pip 19.2.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
user: package femto-13$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.4
user: package femto-13$ twine --version
twine version 1.14.0 (pkginfo: 1.5.0.1, requests: 2.22.0, setuptools: 41.2.0,
requests-toolbelt: 0.9.1, tqdm: 4.35.0)
```

History:

```
  917  git tag -a vX.Y.ZZ  # Don't forget the leading v
  918  git push origin vX.Y.ZZ
  919  python3 setup.py sdist
  920  python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
  921  twine upload dist/*
```

Here is result of twine command:

```
user:package user-13$ twine upload dist/*
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading py_package-X.Y.ZZ.post0.dev0_g83905ac-py3-none-any.whl
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 18.5k/18.5k [00:00<00:00, 37.9kB/s]
NOTE: Try --verbose to see response content.
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: 'X.Y.ZZ.post0.dev0-g83905ac' is an invalid value for Version. Error: Start and end with a letter or numeral containing only ASCII numeric and '.', '_' and '-'. See https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

I have updated tag to 0.0.1 and erased all X.Y.Z tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version `X.Y.ZZ.post0.dev0-g83905ac` is not a valid version number for PyPI. It contains a commit hash `g83905ac`, and [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) says:

> Many build tools integrate with distributed version control systems like Git and Mercurial in order to add an identifying hash to the version identifier. As hashes cannot be ordered reliably such versions are not permitted in the public version field.